# Access select latest rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm looking to create a result in a single step that will provide only the latest (top 1) `ValidFrom` date for each `Code`,

Table1

```
Code    Rate    ValidFrom
A       0%      1/1/2018
B       20%     1/2/2018
A       20%     1/3/2018
A       10%     1/1/2017
B       5%      1/2/2017
C       30%     1/3/2016
```

query result to be the following output:

```
Code    Rate    ValidFrom
B       20%     1/2/2018
A       20%     1/3/2018
C       30%     1/3/2016
```

Grouping on `Code` with the `Max(ValidFrom)` doesnt work becuase the `Rate` is different for each `ValidFrom` date so every record is returned.

The simplest solution is to create an interim query ( Query1 ):

```
SELECT Sub1.Code, Max(Sub1.ValidFrom) AS ValidFrom
FROM Table1 AS Sub1
GROUP BY Sub1.Code;
```

then filter the result using Query2:

```
SELECT Table1.Code,  Table1.Rate, Table1.ValidFrom
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON (Query1.ValidFrom=Table1.ValidFrom) AND (Query1.Code=Table1.Code);
```

But that is messy as it leaves a Query1 only being needed as an interim step and I wanted to find a tidier method.

So, I have tried to work out how to include the SQL for Query1 into Query2 as a subquery (hence the reference to Sub1) but just cant figure it out.

As an alternate solution I have tried to use the TOP 1 type query (Query3):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sub1.Code, Sub1.Rate, Sub1.ValidFrom
FROM Table1 AS Sub1
ORDER BY Sub1.ValidFrom DESC;
```

this just produces one record instead of a record for each code.

I can get it to show each `Code` individually by adding a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sub1.Code, Sub1.Rate, Sub1.ValidFrom
FROM Table1 AS Sub1
WHERE (((Sub1.Code)="C"))
ORDER BY Sub1.ValidFrom DESC;
```

So next attempted to use that as a subquery but that just cant get that to work properly either (Query4):

```
SELECT Table1.Code, Table1.ValidFrom, Table1.Rate
FROM Table1
WHERE 
(SELECT TOP 1 Sub1.Rate
FROM Table1 AS Sub1
WHERE (((Sub1.Code)=Table1.Code))
ORDER BY Sub1.ValidFrom DESC)
```

I clearly have a lot to learn about subqueries but could anyone put me on the right track here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
where t1.validfrom = (select max(tt1.validfrom)
                      from table1 as tt1
                      where tt1.code = t1.code
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, just a minor correction to a missing bracket but otherwise, awesome !